Why is a fibration of $\infty$-operads defined to be a categorical fibration?
In "Higher Algebra," Definition 2.1.2.10, Lurie defines a fibration of $\infty$-operads to be a map of $\infty$-operads which is also a categorical fibration. I'm wondering why exactly it should be a categorical fibration, as opposed to any other kind of fibration; in particular, why inner fibration is not enough. Undoubtedly the fact that I don't have good intuition as to what categorical fibrations encode in the first place plays a role in this.
Skimming chapter 2 of Higher Algebra, it seems to me that most results involving fibrations of $\infty$-operads in fact involve cocartesian fibrations of $\infty$-operads. The definition of $\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathcal{O} / \mathcal{O}'}(\mathcal{C})$ is certainly in terms of categorical fibrations, but the role of this object in the general theory is also rather nebulous to me, so in particular facts such as HA, Proposition 2.1.3.9 saying that the restriction map $\mathrm{Alg}_{/\mathbb{E}_0}(\mathcal{O}) \to \mathrm{Fun}_{\mathbb{E}_0^\otimes}(\Delta^1, \mathcal{O}^\otimes)$ associated to a fibration of $\infty$-operads $\mathcal{O}^\otimes \to \mathbb{E}_0^\otimes$ is a trivial fibration haven't convinced me that categorical fibration is the right notion here (so far).
Thus, I'd like to ask why the definition of fibration of $\infty$-operads is as it is. In particular, I'd be grateful for any fact that follows from this definition which should "reasonably" (or perhaps "intuitively") be true in the general framework of $\infty$-operads, and which would be false if one e.g. replace the adjective "categorical" by, say, "inner."

It is HA.2.1.4.6 that there is a model structure on $\infty$-preoperads whose fibrant objects are $\infty$-operads and fibrations between fibrant objects are precisely the fibrations of $\infty$-operads from Def. 2.1.2.10. When you put your homotopy goggles on, therefore, you cannot really distinguish between fibrations of $\infty$-operads and other morphisms between $\infty$-operads: up to homotopy, they are the same. In particular, a fibration of $\infty$-operads is not something that ''exists'' meaningfully in an $\infty$-category of $\infty$-operads. On the other hand, cocartesian fibrations between $\infty$-operads are homotopically meaningful, and this notion makes sense also in an $\infty$-category of $\infty$-operads, so it is not surprising that you see it appear often in HA as well.
The reason then that categorical fibrations appear, and not just inner fibrations, is similar to the reason this happens in the theory of quasicategories in HTT: Lurie works in a strict setting with model categories and point-set arguments, and therefore it is very convenient for him if certain morphisms have ''strictness properties'' that do not have homotopical meaning, for instance strict lifting properties. In HTT, working with inner fibrations is often not enough, even though every morphism of simplicial sets is an inner fibration up to homotopy, because Lurie would for instance want to use that a morphism $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ lifts equivalences in $\mathcal{D}$ with a given starting point in $\mathcal{C}$ strictly to an equivalence in $\mathcal{C}$. Up to homotopy, it is harmless to add this assumption, so Lurie does this for convenience.
Additionally, certain homotopy limits are modelled by strict limits if sufficiently many morphisms in your situation are fibrations. If you take a fiber of a categorical fibration between fibrant objects, it also models the homotopy fiber in the $\infty$-category of appropriately sized $\infty$-categories. For inner fibrations, this is no longer true. This is another way in which working with categorical fibrations allows you to make more assumptions that do not cause any harm (up to homotopy).
In HA.2.1.2.22 Lurie characterizes the difference between a map of $\infty$-operads that is only an inner fibration, and one that is a categorical fibration. As you see, the latter gives you strict lifting of inert morphisms, which is convenient. (The homotopical version of the lifting problem always holds.)

Adding to this answer it's probably good to mention that even the notion of inner fibrations is not closed under Joyal equivalence and another incarnation of the strict setting through point-set arguments.
